# Viewing CallStack in Visual Studio 2010 when stack overflow exception thrown

Tags: visual-studio-2010, stack-overflow

I want to view the call stack when a stackoverflow exception is thrown. (i.e. I want to pin point what recursive call is causing the stack overflow).
The call stack is cleared and all that I can see is "External Code".

Edit I followed Chris Schmich's advice (post below), now I have a call stack like below, this is just a plain console app that I'm writing, notice that the is no mention of Main() in the screen shot:

[image]

Edit2: I followed Chris Schmich's advice about view the different threads call stacks, however I still can't seem to view my console app's call stack, here's what I can see:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `[External Code]` frame you see is because of the debugger's Just My Code feature.  The debugger is hiding stack frames from you because they are not in your code.  Some details about JMC can be found in [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20140423135248/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2004/07/29/201315.aspx).

You can disable Just My Code by doing the following:

- Debug » Options and Settings... » uncheck "Enable Just My Code (Managed only)" » click OK

You should now be able to see all of the stack frames.

For an example of JMC, when I step into a simple C# console app with JMC enabled, I see only the code in my solution...

[image]

...and with JMC disabled, I see Framework code as well...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, however after following those steps I can now see I can 5 calls in my stack when the exception is thrown. Non of them are from my code. At the top of the stack is .....RunUserAssembly() and at the bottom is [Native to Managed Transition]. Have you any idea what I can do from here to view the part of the call stack I'm interested in?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to take screen shots- i've edited my orginal post and added a screen shot...

Comment: @bplus: that screenshot is from a different thread, which is why you don't see your `Main`.  The stack overflow is probably happening on another thread.  Open the threads window (Debug » Windows » Threads) to view and switch the active thread.  The call stack will update when you switch threads.

Comment: Thanks for the further advice - however I still can't view my call stack, I've posted another screen shot. Thanks again for your help so far!

Comment: Actually, I've now pin pointed by recursive call problem so I can live without the call stack vs2010 help - just wanted to say thanks for your time though!

Answer (score 0):

Check this, Loading Symbols paragraph
[Loading Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx)
They are *.pdb files, and you need to download them from microsoft so you can be able to see external code.