# Type.GetType() throwing a StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I have a problem where this code

```
Type.GetType("Fully qualified assembly name goes here");
```

But get an uncatchable StackOverflowException.

I have managed to instantiate the class from the fully qualified assembly name but get this error when calling GetType with the same name.

To add to this I have watched the offending line of code work in some cases and not in others, with the exact same fully qualified assembly name in both cases.

This is my first StackOverflow question so comments on the structure of it are welcome. :)

Comment: Is there any loop surrounding this code?

Comment: This class is something you have written? If so, could you post the relevant bit of code for it?

Comment: You've come to the right site if you're getting problems with a stack overflow ...

Comment: Have you watched the call stack? (Debug->Windows->Call Stack)... Normally you can see the problem from there.

Comment: Could you try `Type.GetType("System.String")`?

Comment: @xanatos I cannot see the callstack, I've read that it is because there is no room to allocate a stackframe for throwing the exception.

Comment: @JohannThor Try doing this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4149031/613130 to see the cs

Comment: This isn't simple to explain with just the single line of fake code you posted.  You'll need to look for *other* code that runs when Type.GetType() is called.  Like an AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event handler or a static constructor.

Comment: Also what environment is this in: ASP.Net, a console app, etc?  Various hosts like ASP.NET may alter assembly resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some relevant sounding pieces of information that may help from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx :

To determine if there is a problem with your assembly try this:

> GetType causes loading of the assembly specified in typeName. You can also load an assembly using the Load method, and then use the GetType or GetTypes methods of the Assembly class to get Type objects.

If you get an error on `Load(assembly)` then you know the problem isn't with the `GetType()` call.

Also, make sure you're passing in the right type of assembly:

> GetType only works on assemblies loaded from disk. If you call GetType to look up a type defined in a dynamic assembly defined using the System.Reflection.Emit services, you might get inconsistent behavior.