# Assembly.DefinedTypes throws a StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue where the following code can throw a `StackOverflowException`:

```
var t = typeof(SomeType).Assembly.DefinedTypes;
```

Debugging into it, the exception happens in `RuntimeAssembly.cs` at `GetType(this)`:

```
internal RuntimeType[] GetDefinedTypes()
{
    return GetTypes(this);
}
```

It also seems to have something to do with target frameworks. `SomeType` is defined in a project that targets .NET 6. The executing project is targeting .NET 7. If I change the executing project to target .NET 6, the exception goes away.

Accessing `Asssembly.DefinedTypes` is the first call in `Program.cs` so there is no loop of any kind in my code. I've also tried rebooting and rebuilding. `global.json` specifies `7.0.400`.

Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: Weird problem. Where are you making this call? From inside `Main`? Or are you calling it from somewhere unusual, e.g. a type initializer or static constructor?

Comment: `Main`. Literally the very first call in the program.

Comment: got a stacktrace?

Comment: There is no stack trace.

Comment: There's no stack trace when you get a stack overflow exception (for obvious reasons). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49882734/2791540) for other troubleshooting options.

Comment: Not sure it will help but see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499906/2791540)

Comment: Possibly a recursive reference in a static constructor somewhere. Might need an analyzer on the assembly

Comment: @JohnWu I can't get the first one to work. Assembly.Load works fine.

Comment: @Charlieface This is no static constructor. The entire app is literally one line.

Comment: Is your .NET fully up to date? Sounds like a bug in the framework.

Comment: An in the case that it is a bug in the framework, the [runtime team](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime) might be interested to hear about it.

Comment: I have a ticket into MS Support. I'll let you know what I find out. But I got it to repro by having the library project reference UnitsNet and then inheriting from one of its interfaces. Weird stuff.